# SQL - performance in varchar vs. int

Tags: mysql, sql, sql-server, database, oracle

I have a table which has a `primary key` with `varchar` data type. And another table with `foreign key` as `varchar` datatype.

I am making a `join` statement using this pair of `varchar` datatype. Though I am dealing with few number of rows (say hunderd rows), it is taking `60ms`. But when the system will finally be deployed, it will have around thousands of rows.

I read [`Performance of string comparison vs int join in SQL`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431107/performance-of-string-comparison-vs-int-join-in-sql), and concluded that the performance of `SQL` Query depend upon `DB` and number of rows it is dealing with.

But when I am dealing with a very large amount of data, would it matter much?

Should I create a new column with a `number` datatype in both the `table` and `join` the `table` to reduce the time taken by the `SQL` Query.?

Comment: please note that the 60ms delay may be caused by the underlying application code or drivers overhead. It may as well stay like this if add a few thousand rows

Comment: No, either change your primary key type, or leave it alone.  Also, it is not too wise to try to optimize pre-maturely.

Comment: @cha: I din't get you much. I am using SQLyog, will it matter?

Comment: @user2310289: I din't get you too. How to optimize the code?

Comment: I am saying either change your PK now, or wait until you know that you have a problem.  i.e. Find out by loading data whether this will be a problem.

Comment: @user2310289: Actually I cannot modify the primary key, as about hundreds of currently deployed project are working on the same query. And moreover, I am not facing any error; just the time taken by the queries are much more than we need.

Comment: 60ms is too much time?

Comment: Yes, as this is just few rows, if you compare this time with thousand or millions of rows then it would drastically increase.

Comment: For 100 rows this 60ms does not mean anything, you have many items (e.g. LAN speed) influencing this number. Try it on your finally deployed system. If you get performance issues there, you can have a look.

Comment: @Wernfried: and if it is on local machine then.?

Comment: LAN speed was just an example apart from many ohter factors. Try it on your final system and check the result there. In Oracle you have many possibilities to improve your performace, for example RESULT CACHE.

Comment: Numbers might be faster, depending on the degree of precision, but the difference is really small when you consider that an index also has the overhead of a ROWID.

Comment: Is that varchar PK column storing a GUID?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> Should I create a new column with a number datatype in both the table and join the table to reduce the time taken by the SQL Query.?

If you're in a position where you can change the design of the database with ease then yes, your Primary Key should be an integer. Unless there is a really good reason to have an FK as a varchar, then they should be integers as well.

If you can't change the PK or FK fields, then make sure they're indexed properly. This will eventually become a bottleneck though.

Comment: number vs. text is usually a proxy for "artificial key" vs. "natural key."  If there is a good natural key, it may be worth the slight reduction in index efficiency to be able to skip entire table lookups and increase robustness of the code.

Comment: @DougM: yes, but if you consider the most basic code which cannot be modified further then?

Comment: Are you storing artifically generated keys as varchar's, @Veer?

Comment: Yes, the primary key are generated automatically.

Comment: Then there is absolutely no reason whatsoever to store them as varchar.  Int or GUID, never char.

Answer (score 5):

You should use the correct data type for that data that you are representing -- any dubious theoretical performance gains are secondary to the overhead of having to deal with data conversions.

It's really impossible to say what that is based on the question, but most cases are rather obvious. Where they are not obvious are in situations where you have a data element that is represented by a set of digits but which you do not treat as a number -- for example, a phone number.

Clues that you are dealing with this situation are:

- leading zeroes that must be preserved
- no arithmetic operations are carried out on the element.
- string operations are carried out: eg. "take the last four characters"

If that's the case then you probably want to store your "number" as a varchar.

Answer (score 3):

Yes, you should give that a shot.  But before you do, make a test version of your db that you populate with the level of data you expect to have in production, and run some tests on not just SELECT, but also INSERT, UPDATE, and DELETE as well.  Then make a version with integer keys, and perform equvialent tests.

The numeric-keys WILL be faster, for the simple reason that the keys are of smaller size, but the difference may not be noticeable.  Don't blindly trust books when you can test and measure the difference yourself.

(One thing to remember: if there are occasions when all you need from a relation is the value you currently have as its key, your database may run significantly faster if you can skip entire table lookups by just referencing the foreign-key on the records you have.)

Answer (score -1):

It just does not sound right to me. It will use more space result in more reads etc. Then is the varchar the clustered index key? If so the table is going to get very fragmented.