# Performance gain by converting to INTEGER type in SQL for JOIN?

Tags: sql, sql-server, database-performance

Suppose I have `Table_A` (~50m rows) with a column, say `ColA`, which is of `INTEGER` type. I also have `Table_B` with `ColB` (~30m rows), which is of `VARCHAR` type, but that column consists solely of numeric IDs (e.g., '12345'). Suppose I'd like to join these tables like below:

```
SELECT *
FROM Table_A AS a
INNER JOIN Table_B AS b
ON a.ColA = b.ColB
```

I have been told that `JOIN` using `INTEGER` columns are usually faster than doing so using `VARCHAR` columns. But reading through StackOverflow and other resources found via Google didn't help me draw any conclusion on that matter (e.g., [1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332300/is-there-a-real-performance-difference-between-int-and-varchar-primary-keys), [2](http://database-programmer.blogspot.com/2008/01/database-skills-sane-approach-to.html#rule1) and [3](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20559867/sql-performance-in-varchar-vs-int)).

My questions are:

1. Should I **change the column type** for `ColB` to `INTEGER` before joining these two tables? Will that improve the join performance?
2. Suppose I decide to convert the `ColA` to `VARCHAR`, is it the best practice to limit its width/size to the smallest possible or does the size/width of the `VARCHAR` column matter in JOIN performance?
3. Which tool(s) (in addition to calculating the `query_end_time - query_tart_time`) could help me illustrate the query performance improvement, if any, in SQL Server?

Thank you in advanced for your answers/suggestions to any of the above questions!

Comment: I don't think a conversion in your code is going to speed things up. SQL is going to do the same implicit conversion for you when you compare the varchar to integer values. You can test it, but I am pretty sure it will only make a big difference if you change the column types.

Comment: In #1, Do you mean change the column datatype, or do you mean using the `convert()` function?

Comment: @SqlZim, I meant changing the column data type. I suppose using the `convert()` function in the JOIN statement would add to the cost (correct me if I'm wrong)?

Comment: @user1330974 it wouldn't add to the cost, but it probably wouldn't help. It would be the difference between an implicit conversion and an explicit conversion. Just getting rid of the conversions will make a big difference and allow you to take proper advantage of indexes and comparisons without the added overhead.

Comment: Tools to illustrate improvement would be in the statistics and execution plans. e.g. `set statistics xml, io, time on;`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should convert the string representation of a number to a number.  Your references are not appropriate for two reasons:

1. They seem to be more centered on MySQL (although that doesn't matter).
2. They talk about primary keys, rather than joins.

I know of no reference that is going to say that having joins with different types is a good idea.  There might be some situations where it doesn't matter, but you should settle on a single type and a number is better than a string:

- A number is fixed in size.  Strings vary in size.  This adds a wee bit of overhead to indexes and comparison operations.  Not a big deal, but stick with the better one if you have a choice.
- The mixing of data types can preclude the use of indexes.
- The mixing of data types requires conversion operations for each comparison.
- The optimizer statistics for numbers and strings may not be directly comparable (depends on the optimizer).
- You cannot declare foreign key relationships if the types are not the same.

So, stick with the same types.  That is most important.  Integer is marginally better than string, so use that.

Comment: Thank you for the detailed explanation! I'd like to ask a follow-up question to your last sentence: why is `INTEGER` marginally better than `VARCHAR`? If I fix the size of `VARCHAR` column, to say `20` characters, wouldn't that also have the same performance as having an `INTEGER`?

Comment: @user1330974 . . . Variable length keys are a bit less efficient in indexes, and 20 bytes (or really up to 22 bytes) is larger than an integer (4 bytes).