# MySQL: Why it is recommended to JOIN on int instead on varchar field?

Tags: mysql, performance, inner-join

Let's consider this strange situation,
where there's a redundancy of indexes.

```
TableA (item_id, code_key, data01, ... data0n)
TableB (item_id, code_key, dataA1, ... dataAn)
```

Both item_id and code_key are unique and they could be a primary key in both tables. item_id or code_key could be removed from both tables without losing any reference/relation.

It's redundant I know, but this is not the point of the question.
Consider that, both columns are indexed.

Item_id is a INT, codeKey is a VARCHAR(100).

Someone is suggesting that's better  querying:

```
select * from TableA INNER JOIN TableB USING(item_id)
```

rather than :

```
select * from TableA INNER JOIN TableB USING(code_key)
```

I don't see the point of it since both columns are indexed and the performance would be the same.... isn't it?

Is it that having a INT would be faster than having a VARCHAR in the ON clause?Even if they're both indexed?

Comment: Duplicate of [Performance of string comparison vs int join in SQL](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12431107/performance-of-string-comparison-vs-int-join-in-sql)

Comment: Performancewise, the difference is negligible - except on very large datasets. The key factor is whether codekey can change under certain circumstances,

Comment: Your comment, on the contrary of other question, is in line on what I thought. Code_key is inserted and never changes just like item_id. I think that Mysql behind the scenes indexes these columns, so despite to their declaration type they would have the same performance benchmark hit, on operations such like search or join....

Comment: You have 100 people in a room. Is it easier to remember and call them by numbers 1 - 100 or by their first and last name? That's your answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Int comparisons are faster than varchar comparisons, for the simple
>   fact that ints take up much less space than varchars.
>
> This holds true both for unindexed and indexed access. The fastest way
>   to go is an indexed int column.
>
> -- @Robert Munteanu

Hope that helps. There are no much differences, but we value the speed performance. The longer is the varchar the slower it gets.

Answer (score 0):

You seem to be asking about having two columns for the same information.  That is almost always frowned on.

Moving on... Should you have an `INT` or a `VARCHAR`...

Fetching a row costs a lot more (even if cached) than anything to do with the individual columns.  So, while `VARCHAR` might be more costly than `INT`, it is not enough more costly to warrant going out of your way to make the change just for that reason.

The same argument goes for complexity of expressions.

In a related vein, there are multiple reasons for using an `ENUM` *instead of* a `VARCHAR` *when appropriate*.  (Ditto for changing a `VARCHAR` into a `TINYINT`.)

- Smaller --> faster, especially if I/O-bound.
- If indexed, then the index(es) are smaller, too.
- Less disk space

"Normalization" is a deliberate attempt to replace a `VARCHAR` by some size of `INT`.  But there are multiple reasons for that.

- Only one place to change the string, not many rows in many tables.  If this reason exists, then it trumps other considerations.
- Space savings.
- But it adds complexity (now need to `JOIN`).  Hence speed may or may not be improved.

When picking `INT`, always pick the smallest flavor.  `INT` takes 4 bytes; `MEDIUMINT` - 3 bytes, etc.  And pick it based on the range.  And use `UNSIGNED` usually.